# error: incompatible types in assignment. С++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, структуры

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой: при попытке присвоить структурному массиву значения string, получаю ошибку:

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'std::__cxx11::string [32] {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> [32]}'
```

Вот исполняемый код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

string randtitle()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    string r[5] = {"n", "s", "g", "o", "c"};
    return r[1 + rand() % 5];
};

string randartist()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    string r[5] = {"v", "l", "m", "w", "e"};
    return r[1 + rand() % 5];
}

string randstyle()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    string r[5] = {"a", "h", "b", "r", "p"};
    return r[1 + rand() % 5];
}

struct cdinfo
{
    string title[32], artist[32], style[32];
    int year, duration, cost;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, n = 10;
    cdinfo g[n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        g[i].title = randtitle();
        g[i].artist = randartist();
        g[i].style = randstyle();
        g[i].year = 1990 + rand() * 2005;
        g[i].duration = 30 + rand() % 50;
        g[i].cost = 60 + rand() % 150;
    }
}
```

Comment: После `struct test {}` должно быть `;`

Comment: + если используете массивы размер должен быть известен при компиляции, смотрите в сторону векторов

Comment: Исправил, одной ошибкой меньше, но сути не меняет

Comment: `string title[32]` и подобное - это массив из 32 строк, а не строка с 32 символами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну у вас же, например

```
string title[32];
```

а вы пытаетесь присвоить массиву что?

```
g[i].title=randtitle();
```

Просто строку.

Вас же не удивляет, что

```
int a[10];

a = 5;
```

не сработает? тогда почему вы считаете, что можно присваивать массиву один элемент?...

Comment: А как мне тогда нужное значение присвоить?

Comment: Все зависит от того, *чему и что* вы хотите присвоить. Откуда же мне знать, что нужно **вам**?

Comment: В структуре есть строка, и я пытаюсь ей присвоить строку через функцию, которая выбирает случайное значение. Я присваиваю строку к строке, что не так?

Comment: Тогда объявляйте ее как строку, а не как массив. Сейчас у вас в структуре - **массивы строк**. Строки - это вот так: `struct cdinfo
        {
            string title,artist,style; ...`

Comment: Да, спасибо, до меня дошло. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - принимайте :)

Comment: Ну раз так принципиально, ладненько

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Вместо

```
string title[32],artist[32],style[32];
```

Нужно было записать

```
string title,artist,style;
```

Comment: не решено. Если rand()%5 вернет 4, то вы получите удар ниже пояса

Comment: Обязательно исправлю